# Google.Apis.Request.RequestsError - Not Authorized to access this resource

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

The situation is easy : I've created a winform application that reads/creates users & groups in our G-suite environment.
Everything is working fine... but only for my (admin)account.

The question is simple : how to make your application (with your secret embedded in my code) available for all users of your domain ?

Thanks for any useful help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that there is no other way than to grant specific users access as admin (via the admin-console).

Since users must identify themselves via Google, the permissions are given by Google. So a secretary cannot use my application (and my admin-rights) to e.g. create a new user.